# Sorted(list, key=itemgetter) not sorting a list of items properly in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
list1 = ["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]

from operator import itemgetter

def solution(data):

    parse_list = []
    parse_list2 = []
    final_solution = []
    for x in data:
        y = x.split('.')
        if len(y) == 1:
            x = "{}.{}.{}".format(y[0], '-1', '-1')
            parse_list.append(x)
        if len(y) == 2:
            x = "{}.{}.{}".format(y[0], y[1], '-1')
            parse_list.append(x)
        if len(y) == 3:
            x = "{}.{}.{}".format(y[0], y[1], y[2])
            parse_list.append(x)
    print(parse_list)

    parse_list2 = sorted(parse_list, key=itemgetter(0, 1, 2))

    # print(parse_list)
    print(parse_list2)

    def unparse(x):

        y = x.split('.')
        if int(y[1]) < 0:
            x = '{}'.format(y[0])
            final_solution.append(x)
            return
        if int(y[2]) == -1:
            x = '{}.{}'.format(y[0], y[1],)
            final_solution.append(x)
            return
        if int(y[2]) >= 0:
            x = '{}.{}.{}'.format(y[0], y[1], y[2])
            final_solution.append(x)
            return
    for x in parse_list2:
        x = unparse(x)
    print(final_solution)
```

output:

```
['1.11.-1', '2.0.0', '1.2.-1', '2.-1.-1', '0.1.-1', '1.2.1', '1.1.1', '2.0.-1']
['0.1.-1', '1.11.-1', '1.1.1', '1.2.-1', '1.2.1', '2.-1.-1', '2.0.0', '2.0.-1']
['0.1', '1.11', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '2', '2.0.0', '2.0']
```

I do not understand why

```
parse_list2 = sorted(parse_list, key=itemgetter(0, 1, 2))
```

does not sort the output to

```
['1.11.-1', '2.0.0', '1.2.-1', '2.-1.-1', '0.1.-1', '1.2.1', '1.1.1', '2.0.-1']
['0.1.-1', '1.1.1', '1.2.-1', '1.2.1', '1.11.-1', '2.-1.-1', '2.0.0', '2.0.-1']
['0.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.11', '2', '2.0.0', '2.0']
```

because 2 is lower than 11

Please can somebody help me tweak *my* code to work (as opposed to giving me a different, yet functional code) or explain to me why my logic will not work.

Comment: `"11" < "2"` is `True` Because `"1" < "2"`. If you want to compare digits, you either have to turn them into integers or floats for them to sort correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Strings are lexicographically ordered. Parse them to ints. Is the goal here to simply sort these version strings that have negative numbers? What's the problem description? Surely there's a better way to solve this, whatever it is...

Comment: All you're doing is sorting on the first 3 *characters* of each string.  It's not trying to interpret multi-character fields.  So for `'1.11.-1'`, it's using `('1', '.', '1')` as the sort key.

Comment: Can somebody give me a pointer on turning them into ints? I tried, but I ran into the problem of it not liking me trying to change a list into type integer.

Comment: `itemgetter(0, 1, 2)` is getting the first, second and third **character** in the string, not the numbers. Why don't you store them as tuples of ints `(int(y[0]), int(y[1]), int(y[2]))` and just sort them (no special key argument needed)?

Answer (score 2):

Your values are not sorted, because they are comparing strings, not integers.

Here's how I would sort them instead:

```
def toIntList(x):
    intList = []
    for value in x.split("."):
        intList.append(int(value))
    return intList

list1 = ["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]

# Using a function
sort1 = sorted(list1, key=toIntList)

# Using a lambda-function:
sort2 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(".")])

print(list1) # Output: ['1.11', '2.0.0', '1.2', '2', '0.1', '1.2.1', '1.1.1', '2.0']
print(sort1) # Output: ['0.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.11', '2', '2.0', '2.0.0']
print(sort2) # Output: ['0.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.11', '2', '2.0', '2.0.0']
```

Comment: Nice approach! The author asked not to provide a different solution though.

Answer (score 1):

**Some tips:**

- `import`s always at the start (I removed it because I don't use it anymore but keep them always at the top of the file, usually three blocks of imports, standard libraries first, third-party libraries second, and imports to other files of your program third)
- 2 blank lines between first level function and class declarations
- `elif` will not try the condition if the previous was true, so we avoid unnecesary condition checking.
- `parse_list` is going to store tuples of three integers such as `(1, 11, -1)`.
- `parse_list = sorted(parse_list)` is equivalent to `parse_list.sort()` which does it in place.
- The `unparse` function is going to return each value instead of appending to a `final_solution` list that belongs to the `solution` function and not to the `unparse` function.

```py
def solution(data):
    parse_list = []
    for x in data:
        y = x.split('.')
        if len(y) == 1:
            parse_list.append((int(y[0]), -1, -1))
        elif len(y) == 2:
            parse_list.append((int(y[0]), int(y[1]), -1))
        elif len(y) == 3:
            parse_list.append((int(y[0]), int(y[1]), int(y[2])))
    print(parse_list)

    parse_list.sort()
    print(parse_list)

    def unparse(x):
        if x[1] < 0:
            return '{}'.format(x[0])
        if x[2] < 0:
            return '{}.{}'.format(x[0], x[1])
        return '{}.{}.{}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2])

    final_solution = []
    for x in parse_list:
        final_solution.append(unparse(x))
    print(final_solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]
    solution(list1)
```

This could also be optimized:

```py
def solution(data):
    parse_list = sorted([tuple(map(int, item.split('.'))) for item in data])
    final_solution = ['.'.join(map(str, item)) for item in parse_list]
    print(final_solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ["1.11", "2.0.0", "1.2", "2", "0.1", "1.2.1", "1.1.1", "2.0"]
    solution(list1)
```

Let's break this solution down:

1. `[doSomethingWith(item) for item in data]` creates a list where each element is whatever `doSomethingWith(item)` is, using each time one of the elements of `data`.
2. `doSomethingWith(item)` in our case is `tuple(map(int, item.split('.')))`:

   1. `item` is for example `"1.11"`
   2. `item.split('.')` gives us a list of strings: `["1", "11"]`
   3. `map(f, iterable)` applies the function `f` to every element of iterable and returns a list-like object (it is not exactly a list but similar). In our case `f` is `int` so we are converting the substrings to integers: `[1, 11]` <-- Not really a list but similar
   4. We convert this list-like object into a tuple with the external `tuple()`: `(1, 11)`
3. The outside `sorted()` will sort this list, no need to worry about missing elements as `(1, 0) < (1, 0, 0)` so they will sort properly.
4. So `parse_list` is an already sorted list of tuples of integers: `[(0, 1), (1, 1, 1), ...]`
5. Again a `[doSomethingWith(item) for item in parse_list]` statement, so we are creating a new list doing something to every element in `parse_list`.
6. `doSomethingWith(item)` in this case is `'.'.join(map(str, item))`:

   1. `item` is for example `(1, 11)`
   2. `map(str, item)` is converting every element of `item` we have into strings: `["1", "11"]` <-- Not really a list but similar
   3. `'.'.join()` joins a list of strins by '.': `"1.11"`
7. So `final_result` is the desired output: `["0.1", "1.1.1", ...]`